# Change font of jTextfield in jDatePicker in Java

Tags: java, swing

I have downloaded a jDatePicker library and embedded it into my application successfully. This is just a simple jdatepicker.jar file.

I have this simple code to add jDatePicker in my application

```
public JDatePickerImpl JDatePickerDemo() 
{
        UtilDateModel model = new UtilDateModel();
        model.setDate(1990, 8, 24);
        model.setSelected(true);
        JDatePanelImpl datePanel = new JDatePanelImpl(model);
        JDatePickerImpl datePicker = new JDatePickerImpl(datePanel, new DateLabelFormatter());
        return datePicker;      
}
```

this adds jDatePicker in my application

[image]

But the fonts in this above textField is very small, i want to increase its font size. How can I do?

I also have a class with it to format date in textfield, may be that can help but I don't know

```
public class DateLabelFormatter extends AbstractFormatter 
{
    private String datePattern = "yyyy-MM-dd";
    private SimpleDateFormat dateFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat(datePattern);

    @Override
    public Object stringToValue(String text) throws ParseException {
        return dateFormatter.parseObject(text);
    }
}
```

Comment: there are two-three different workarounds thats called JDatePicker, isn't it

Comment: Since we have no idea which date-picker you're using (there are many and you haven't specified), your best bet is to look it up in their documentation. If you can't find anything, then contact support on the website from which you downloaded your date-picker.

Comment: I have used http://sourceforge.net/projects/jdatepicker/ and they have discontinued its development even the site domain is also expired. I used many other datepicker but this one is great just need to change font size the rest is just awesome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`I have used sourceforge.net/projects/jdatepicker ...`

If you unroll the jar from that site, you can inspect the classes and study their public API.  Upon doing this, you will see that there's a class called `JDatePickerImpl`. Somehwere I assume, you be instantiating this.

Upon creating an instance of this, you'll see that you have access to its internal text field, which is a `JFormattedTextField`. From there, you can change its font:

```
JDatePickerImpl datePicker = new JDatePickerImpl(...);
JFormattedTextField textField = datePicker.getJFormattedTextField();
textField.setFont(new Font("Some-Font-Name", Font.BOLD, 12));
```

Comment: WOW man excellent Man. Thanks alot. I thought there isn't any solution so I started with my own creation of new one. Great

Answer (score 0):

```
Font font = new Font("Courier", Font.BOLD,12);

//set font for JTextField
field.setFont(font);
```

http://www.java-examples.com/change-font-jtextfield-example

Comment: As I said its a jar library and I don't have access to it's field component. I just have above code and that's all to create and add jDatePicker.